# Elasticsearch aggregation from java scripted field

Tags: elasticsearch

For simplicity, let's say I have two fields: TRIP_START_DATE (in date format) and TRIP_NIGHTS.

I can run a simple aggregation which will convert dates to date of the week:

```
aggs <- '{
        "aggs": {
          "dept": {
            "filter": {
              "range": {
                "TRIP_START_DATE": {
                  "gte": "2014-01-01",
                  "lte": "2014-12-31"
                }
              }
            },
            "aggs": {
              "weekday": {
                "terms": {
                  "script": "Date date = new Date(doc[\'TRIP_START_DATE\'].value) ; java.text.SimpleDateFormat format = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat(\'EEE\');format.format(date)" 
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }'
```

Is it possible to add another aggregation which returns the average TRIP_NIGHTS per weekday?

Thanks for the help.

Carlos

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer mostly by trial and error:

```
aggs <- '{
        "aggs": {
          "dept": {
            "filter": {
              "range": {
                "TRIP_START_DATE": {
                  "gte": "2014-01-01",
                  "lte": "2014-12-31"
                }
              }
            },
            "aggs": {
              "weekday": {
                "terms": {
                  "script": "Date date = new Date(doc[\'TRIP_START_DATE\'].value) ; java.text.SimpleDateFormat format = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat(\'EEE\');format.format(date)" 
                },
                "aggs": {
                  "stay": {
                    "percentiles": {
                      "script": "doc[\'TRIP_NIGHTS\'].value",
                        "percents": [
                          50
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }  
          }
        }
      }'
```

Carlos